# 2.93.5 - only Grab and Snake Hook tools working correctly in Sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I uploaded 2.93.5 update to my MacBook Pro mid-2012 running macOS 10.15.7 today.  Now only the Grab and Snake Hook sculpt tools work as they should.  Some draw tools appear to have some impact on the the default sculpt mesh but only insofar as a form of smoothing.  Alt+ selection makes no difference to the tools.  I have turned Dynotopo on and off, reset to factory defaults and tried reboots and new files but there is no change. The same is happening on 3.0 Alpha which I downloaded after.  This problem did not occur in 2.93.4.  Any explanation of the possible problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am unable to use any of the sculpting tools in Blender version 2.93.4 or 3.0 Alpha with my Huion Inspiroy Q11k. The latest driver has been loaded for the tablet but still no change.  The only way I can select any of the sculpting tools other than Grab and Snake Hook is to use the trackpad on my MacBook Pro mid-2012. I have been unable to find a reason or a solution and Blender appear to be unable to resolve the issue either.